# How can I call a method from my bindings and override in iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this class:

```
public class ExtSwitch : Switch
{
    public static readonly 
        BindableProperty SwitchOutsideOvalColorProperty = 
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(SwitchOutsideOvalColor), 
        typeof(Color), 
        typeof(ExtSwitch), 
        Color.Default, 
        propertyChanged: HandleOutsidePropertyChanged);
    public Color SwitchOutsideOvalColor { 
        get => (Color)GetValue(SwitchOutsideOvalColorProperty); 
        set => SetValue(SwitchOutsideOvalColorProperty, value); }

    public void HandleOutsidePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
        var a = 99;
    }
}
```

and I am trying to create an iOS version that I would like to respond to the HandleOutsidePropertyChanged(). I tried this:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtSwitch), typeof(ExtSwitchRenderer))]
namespace Japanese.iOS
{
    class ExtSwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
    {

       public override void HandleOutsidePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
       {
          var a = 99;
       }

    }
}
```

But I am getting an error saying no suitable method found to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HandleOutsidePropertyChanged is a method of ExtSwitch, ExtSwitchRenderer inherits from  SwitchRenderer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
public void HandleOutsidePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    var a = 99;
}
```

You need to do this.

```
public void HandleOutsidePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, Color oldValue, Color newValue)
{
    var a = 99;
}
```

Then you can override.